# Postgres pg_ctl restart is not working

Tags: postgresql

I tried to restart Postgres(Version 9.6) after editing the postgresql.conf file .
But its not working

```
    pg_ctl stop
```

waiting for server to shut down............................................................... failed
pg_ctl: server does not shut down

when I try to connect to Postgres , it says "Server is shutting down" and I am not able to connect .Below is what I am getting for pg_ctl start

```
    pg_ctl start
```

2018-02-24 21:11:12 CET FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
2018-02-24 21:11:12 CET HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 42946) running in data directory "/pgDATA/data"?

I tried to kill 42946. But still I am getting the same error .

```
  pg_ctl status
```

This shows that the sever is running . But not able to connect .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should look into the log file; maybe you get a clue from it.

If nothing else works, try `pg_ctl stop -m i` to force PostgreSQL to stop.

If that doesn't work either, check if a process is in uninterruptible sleep. That would necessitate a reboot of the machine.

Comment: *sigh*. Can I stop the container where it's running, will it take care of it?

Comment: That should do it, yes. But then it *should* also be possible to stop PostgreSQL. What is the state of the server process?

Comment: Too late... I docker stopped. I also destroyed the container and re-run with log rotation in place (13gb of stdout managed by docker in a big file). Everything came back up ok. I love docker.